# StreamReader issue finding file

Tags: c#, input, io, streamreader

The following was given by my instructor and on my friends Win 7 it works just fine. I have tried my work laptop and my personal desktop...keeps finding the following error

I dont get it...I went as far as changing permissions to the directory to everyone just for kicks...it works on his copy paste but not mine.

"Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Users\Wookie\My Documents\'."

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {

 // This line of code gets the path to the My Documents Folder
 string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
 (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

 Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name in My Documents: ");
 string input = Console.ReadLine();

 // concatenate the path to the file name
 string path = environment + input;

 // now we can use the full path to get the document
 StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);
 int n = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("read {0}", n);

 Console.ReadLine();
 }//End Main()
}//End class Program
```

Comment: You say it works fine on your friends Windows 7, what operating system are you trying to run it on.

Comment: Add a `Console.Writeline(path)` and check very carefully if it exists.

Comment: For what it is worth it does work on my Laptop as well, running 64 bit Windows 7. as pointed out by Henk and the answers given, double check that the path/file does exist.

Comment: anyway to get around this....I have tried the below idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try whether the file actually exists from your program's point of view. Of course, replace `yourfile.txt` with the filename of the file you are looking for.

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "yourfile.txt");
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(path));
```

If it doesn't, try the same in your file system explorer. Otherwise, are you sure you've entered the file name correctly? Try hard-coding it temporarily. The above code also shows how you should combine paths (note the lack of a slash (`\`) as it is inserted automatically) and how to check whether a file (or directory, using `Directory.Exists()`) exists. This may be of use in finding where the problem is.

Comment: C:\Users\Wookie\Documents\    and the file is test.txt

Comment: Is there a special way to access My Documents under a user. I have gone to properties and copied the exact directory as written in there and it still states that it does not exist...

Answer (score 2):

Just for good coding habit use `Path.Combine` to concatenate paths.
And `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead "\" as a good practice.

Example:

```
 string path = Path.Combine(environment,  input);
```